# How can I use a pip requirements file to uninstall as well as install packages?

Tags: python, pip

I have a pip requirements file that changes during development.

Can `pip` be made to **uninstall** packages that do not appear in the requirements file as well as installing those that do appear? Is there a standard method?

This would allow the pip requirements file to be the canonical list of packages - an 'if and only if' approach.

**Update**: I suggested it as a new feature at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/716

Comment: Do you REALLY want pip uninstalling arbitrary packages just because your program doesn't require them?  Sounds just a little dangerous...

Comment: @ScottHunter If you're in a virtualenv without site packages, it's a reasonable thing to want to do.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes if using a controlled (virtual) environment where I want to certain of what's there - and that's there nothing else present that could possibly cause problems, e.g. unexpected dependencies.

Comment: @MichaelMior If that's the answer then please add as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: @wodow Done. Only reason I didn't post as an answer is because there's probably a more helpful solution that can get you to what you want.

Comment: Could possibly be an option @ScottHunter; probably by default follow the existing model so that multiple invocations with different requirements files "appends" the new installs, but given a "canonical" flag `pip` would do whatever is necessary to bring the installations into line. Because when you know you want this you know you want it, it's not a risk, it's a specification.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do that with pip.

Comment: What I forgot to mention in the original answer is that this is possible with [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/).

Comment: as Stephen says below: `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @Ommit  This does not uninstall packages which don't appear in the requirements file. It uninstalls all packages which do appear in the file.

Comment: @Micheal Mior, ah, I didn't pay close enough attention to the original question. My bad.

Comment: Add a `-y` to @Ommit 's command to avoid having to press Y and enter many many times. Learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Just to add: `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt` will only uninstall the versions in your requirements.txt. If you uninstall `boto3==1.10.0` for example, `pip freeze` will show `boto3==1.0.1` if you have installed it (or any older version) previously.

Comment: You are wrong.
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt is the correct answer

Comment: @PedroMachado This really depends on what you're trying to do. That will uninstall packages listed in the file, which is not what the original question asked to do.

Answer (score 179):

This should uninstall anything not in requirements.txt:

```
pip freeze | grep -v -f requirements.txt - | grep -v '^#' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Although this won't work quite right with packages installed with `-e`, i.e. from a git repository or similar. To skip those, just filter out packages starting with the `-e` flag:

```
pip freeze | grep -v -f requirements.txt - | grep -v '^#' | grep -v '^-e ' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Then, obviously:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Update for 2016:**
You probably don't really want to actually use the above approach, though. [Check out `pip-tools` and `pip-sync`](http://nvie.com/posts/better-package-management/#virtue-2-have-your-envs-reflect-your-specs) which accomplish what you are probably looking to do in a much more robust way.

https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools

**Update for May, 2016:**

You can now also use `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt`, however this accomplishes basically the opposite - it uninstalls everything in `requirements.txt`

**Update for May, 2019:**

Check out [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/). A lot has happened in the world of package management that makes this sort of question a bit obsolete. I'm actually still quite happily using pip-tools, though.

Comment: That would be nice. Seems to me like a good way to force devs to be explicit about their dependencies by breaking everything if they install something on one host manually without updating their requirements.txt. I'd be interested to see what kind of feedback a pull request adding that functionality would generate.

Comment: This is the correct answer! I put this in my `project.config` file for Django on Elastic Beanstalk: `05_pip_clean:
    command: "pip freeze | grep -v -f requirements.txt - | grep -v '^#' | xargs pip uninstall -y"`. Now I can rollback pip packages without rebuilding my environment just by using comments in `requirements.txt`. This is saving me real downtime. Thank you!

Comment: is there ever an output of pip freeze starting with #? In other words, is the second grep necessary?

Comment: @xxor Good question! I'm not sure whether `pip freeze` will ever output a `#` at the beginning of a line. I don't see anything obvious in the pip source that would indicate that it does either ( https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/operations/freeze.py ) however since the requirements file spec allows for it, and I've seen folks use it, I included it! https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirements-file-format

Comment: the requirements file allows for comments. However pip freeze does not make comments, afaik. (BTW I upvoted this answer despite that I think the second grep isn´t needed, because I was looking for this). Now, I have another question: what is the dash at the end of the first grep doing?

Comment: Not sure if `pip freeze` makes comments, but someday they may add it to the API, and if they do, it will be valid. If they don't, then the above is a no-op. The dash allows you to use stdin from the previous command, in this case, the dash is telling grep to compare the contents of requirements.txt to the output of `pip freeze` (the output of `pip freeze` in this context is synonymous with stdin)

Comment: I didn't even take time to read this yet, but already updated for '16 on a nearly three year old post. Nice job! +1

Comment: I highly recommended pip-tools. +1

Comment: Still useful today until I switch to pip-tools. I just had to add -r to xargs command:
pip freeze | grep -v -f requirements.txt - | grep -v '^#' | xargs -r pip uninstall -y

Answer (score 42):

You can now pass the `-r requirements.txt` argument to `pip uninstall`.

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y
```

At least as of `pip` 8.1.2, `pip help uninstall` shows:

```
...
Uninstall Options:
  -r, --requirement <file>    Uninstall all the packages listed in the given requirements file.  This option can be
                              used multiple times.
...
```

Comment: This does not uninstall packages which do not appear in the file. It uninstalls packages which *do* appear in the file.

Comment: Sigh... It was *so close* to something useful. Who would want to uninstall *everything but* properly-tracked dependencies?

Comment: I do, @bukzor, because I installed some packages, used them, and now want to remove them again because I don't need them anymore, and I want the image to be lighter.

Comment: @NeilG Then you need to ensure there was an empty intersection between the old packages and the newly installed ones

Comment: Thanks @creanion, yes, I use `pip freeze` at different points to capture the installed set so I can subtract one from the other later for the `pip uninstall`.

Answer (score 29):

It's not a feature of `pip`, no. If you really want such a thing, you could write a script to compare the output of `pip freeze` with your `requirements.txt`, but it would likely be more hassle than it's worth.

Using [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/), it is easier and more reliable to just create a clean environment and (re)install from `requirements.txt`, like:

```
deactivate
rm -rf venv/
virtualenv venv/
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: It could be useful to just uninstall packages that aren't in the requirements file if some of the packages (PIL, lxml, etc) require lengthy compilation - especially if this is taking place on a live server that is using the virtual environment.

Comment: @melinath If they aren't in your requirements file and they are already installed, then the compilation should never have to happen again.

Comment: @MichaelMior - unless you were to, say, wipe the entire virtualenv, as this answer suggests.

Comment: @melinath But if you wipe the virtualenv and the package is not required (and not in your `requirements.txt`), why would it ever get installed again?

Comment: @MichaelMior I'll try stating my original comment more explicitly. It seems like you may have misunderstood the point I was making.

Imagine a simple requirements file that contains PIL and lxml. But then you decide you don't need lxml any more, and you remove it from the requirements file. If you do as this answer suggests, and wipe the virtualenv, you then have to reinstall (and recompile) PIL.

It would be more efficient to have the option of simply uninstalling lxml (i.e. all packages not in the requirements file.)

Comment: @melinath Understood :) That makes more sense now.

Answer (score 17):

you can create a new file with all installed packages

```
pip freeze > uninstall.txt
```

and then uninstall all of those

```
pip uninstall -r uninstall.txt -y
```

and then finally re-install the packages you had in your original requirements.txt file

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: that's a clever workaround  haven't thought of that

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple solution that works:

`pip uninstall $(pip freeze) -y`

Comment: it will uninstall all packages not only from your current project's  `requirements.txt`

Comment: @SaadAbbasi that's true. But the answer can easily be adapted by just adding the command to install all packages from the requirements file afterwards. So the solution would be 
`pip uninstall $(pip freeze) -y && pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question (but a good one), and things have changed substantially since it was asked.

There's an offhand reference to `pip-sync` in another answer, but deserves its own answer, because it solves precisely the OP's problem.

[pip-sync](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#example-usage-for-pip-sync) takes a `requirements.txt` file as input, and "trues up" your current Python environment so that it matches *exactly* what's in that `requirements.txt`. This includes *removing* any packages that are present in your env but absent from  `requirements.txt`.

Example: Suppose we want our env to contain (only) 3 libraries: `libA`, `libB`, and `libC`, like so:

```
> cat requirements.txt
libA==1.0
libB==1.1
libC==1.2
```

But our env currently contains `libC` and `libD`:

```
> pip freeze
libC==1.2
libD==1.3
```

Running pip-sync will result in this, which was our desired final state:

```
> pip-sync requirements.txt
> pip freeze
libA==1.0
libB==1.1
libC==1.2
```

Comment: beware, if you have a globally installed pip-tools, it will not uninstall in your currently activated virtualenv...still strange, but otherwise the most straight forward requirements management tool I know.

Answer (score 3):

Stephen's proposal is a nice idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work
if you include only direct requirements in your file, which sounds
cleaner to me.

All dependencies will be uninstalled,
including even `distribute`, breaking down `pip` itself.

#### Maintaining a clean requirements file while version tracking a virtual environment

Here is how I try to version-track my virtual environment.
I try to maintain a minimal `requirements.txt`, including only
the direct requirements, and not even mentioning version constraints where
I'm not sure.

But besides, I keep, and include in version tracking (say git),
the actual status of my virtualenv in a `venv.pip` file.

Here is a sample workflow:

---

setup virtualenv workspace, with version tracking:

```
mkdir /tmp/pip_uninstalling
cd /tmp/pip_uninstalling
virtualenv venv
. venv/bin/activate
```

initialize version tracking system:

```
git init
echo venv > .gitignore
pip freeze > venv.pip
git add .gitignore venv.pip
git commit -m "Python project with venv"
```

install a package with dependencies, include it in requirements file:

```
echo flask > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip freeze > venv.pip
```

Now start building your app, then commit and start a new branch:

```
vim myapp.py
git commit -am "Simple flask application"
git checkout -b "experiments"
```

install an extra package:

```
echo flask-script >> requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip freeze > venv.pip
```

... play with it, and then come back to earlier version

```
vim manage.py
git commit -am "Playing with flask-script"
git checkout master
```

Now uninstall extraneous packages:

```
pip freeze | grep -v -f venv.pip | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

I suppose the process can be automated with git hooks, but let's not go off topic.

Of course, it makes sense then to use some package caching system
or local repository like [pip2pi](https://github.com/wolever/pip2pi)

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off @stephen-j-fuhry here is a powershell equivalent I use:

```
pip freeze | ? { $_ -notmatch ((gc req.txt) -join "|") }
```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly answer the question, a better alternative to `requirements.txt` now is using a [`Pipfile`](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile). This functions similarly to a Ruby `Gemfile`. Currently, you need to make use of the [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tool but hopefully this will eventually be incorporated into `pip`. This provides the `pipenv clean` command which does what you want.

(Note that you can import an existing `requirements.txt` with `pipenv install -r requirements.txt`. After this you should have a `Pipfile` and the `requirements.txt` can be removed.)

Answer (score -4):

It is possible now using:

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: This does not uninstall packages which don't appear in the requirements file. It uninstalls all packages which *do* appear in the file.