# How to reproduce a Python environment with pip replacing the existing environment?

Tags: python, pip

Python environment has been traditionally reproduced with a `requirements.txt` file. This works only if you're willing to create a new environment

#### Reproduce Python Env with a new environment

```
$ python -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ pip list

  pkg1==1.0.0
  pkg2==1.0.0
  pkg2_dep==1.0.0 # Not written in requirement.txt
```

#### Reproduce Python Env with an existing environment

```
$ python -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate
$ pip install requirements.txt

# Made changes to requirements.txt
# Removed pk2==1.0.0
$ pip install requirements.txt
$ pip list

  pkg1==1.0.0
  pkg2==1.0.0 # Should be uninstalled!
  pkg2_dep==1.0.0 # this too
```

The limitation above is due to pip being unable to [install and uninstall together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176968/how-can-i-use-a-pip-requirements-file-to-uninstall-as-well-as-install-packages). Other languages support this by using lock files.

---

#### Question:

- How to use pip to reproduce a Python environment with `requirements.txt` or the new `pyproject.toml`?
- If not possible with pip, what other solutions from other packager-manager exists for this purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176968/how-can-i-use-a-pip-requirements-file-to-uninstall-as-well-as-install-packages

Comment: Do you get euphoria out of pointing out duplicates?  I've linked that question already and mention its a limitation of pip but that itself does not answer my question directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a pip requirements file to uninstall as well as install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176968/how-can-i-use-a-pip-requirements-file-to-uninstall-as-well-as-install-packages)

Comment: Well sorry I didn't click on your link by reading first few paragraphs and knew what you were asking for, I did spend the effort to try to find you an answer, no euphoria was produced during the process.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski, no, that question pertains purely about using requirements.txt to do this. This question asks how to directly reproduce a Python environment using any strategy from pip. Installing and uninstalling packages together using requirements.txt is already solved as impossible but my question differs asking about pip in general

Comment: Have you tried pipenv?

Comment: If you're suggesting pipenv, then please add it as an answer below with example. Thanks, @James Lin.

Comment: Good idea to make a separate question asking about `pyproject.toml`? I expect the answer to be "it's impossible".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at pipenv https://docs.pipenv.org/#pipenv-clean

```
clean
Uninstalls all packages not specified in Pipfile.lock.

pipenv clean [OPTIONS]
```